"His resting place will be Damascus" - what is the meaning of this Midrash?
The Midrash Rabbah (Shir HaShirim Rabbah 7:5) expounds on the posuk: "and Damascus shall his resting place be" (Zecharyah 9:1) that Damascus will be "the resting place of Moshiach":

Another matter, Ḥadrakh, this is the messianic king who is destined to guide [lehadrikh] all mankind in repentance before the Holy One blessed be He. “Damascus is His resting place” (Zechariah 9:1). Is Damascus His resting place? But is His resting place not the Temple, as it is stated: “This is My resting place forever” (Psalms 132:14)? He said to him: Jerusalem is destined to expand on all its sides until it reaches the gates of Damascus, and all the exiles will come and rest under its auspices, to realize what is stated: “Damascus is His resting place,” His resting place will reach Damascus.

Why will Damascus be the resting place of Moshiach? Why does the Midrash teach us this and what is the deeper meaning behind the idea that this specific place will be the resting place of Moshiach (keep in mind the idea that Jerusalem will extend to Damascus, but that is not the question).
Any meforshim/seforim on this?

Interesting - 1st noticed this inyan years ago during the קול מבשר section of piyutim on Hoshana Rabba where it says קול שימי עד דמשק משכנותייך indicating that somehow the concept of a mikdash will someday extend to Damascus.  Interesting to note that דמשק is an anagram of מקדש and perhaps that's the kernel hint that launches the midrash. BTW - the original source of this midrash is in the earlier ספרי at the very beginning of Devarim - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Devarim.1.19

@EraserX Thanks for sharing. I understand the anagram, but there must be a reason why it does mention Damascus as resting place and saw the need to do that, and not referring to Jerusalem itself.

To expand upon my comment above:
מלך המשיח as the one who will rule in Yerushalayim and build the mikdash is inherently connected to Yerushalayim/mikdash upon which the midrash says will extend their boundaries to דמשק.
Now why specifically דמשק?
Before we get into a deeper meaning behind the midrash, it is worth noting what the דעת מקרא on זכריה ט:א posits (based on a Radak there) - that Zecharia's נבואה happened at the time when עולי בבל were approaching דמשק on their way to ארץ ישראל:

So if this is correct, the midrash happens to be commenting on a נבואה that actually happened in the proximity of דמשק and was projecting what would happen in דמשק in the future.
I have noticed kabbalistic sources which delve into the significance of דמשק here, namely the ערבי נחל על פרשת לך לך (by רב דוד שלמה אייבשיץ) who states that in direct contrast to the מקדש there is a קליפה called דמשק which has the exact same letters as מקדש.  See the link above and review the sections before and after my quote to get a better sense of what he is trying to say.
I have seen those who write that the אריז"ל mentions some connected ideas - see  his לקוטי_תורה for more on that within his comments on זכריה ט:א
Also of interest:

The earliest one I have seen who noticed that דמשק is an anagram of מקדש is from over 800 years ago in the פירוש הרוקח על שיר השירים ז:ה - I wouldn't be surprised if this parallel partly inspired the words of the midrash
the original source of this midrash is in the earlier ספרי at the very beginning of Devarim


Thanks. Interesting Radak. Especially the last part where it says that Gaza and Damascus will embrace the faith of Yisroel. However, I still don't understand why Moshiach's resting place will be Damascus. Besides the opinion that Jerusalem will reach to it, what does it mean and why is this?

I tried to address that above when I mentioned "מלך המשיח as the one who will rule in Yerushalayim and build the mikdash is inherently connected to Yerushalayim/mikdash". I do understand that there's much room for improvement/expansion re: a full answer to your question.

No source, but I suggest that it's possible that the midrash is tying this verse to a tradition brought by Reish Lakish in Bavli Eruvin 19a that states that one of the possible locations for the entrance to Gan Eden was in Domaskanin (Damascus). This would explain why the Mashiach's resting place had to stretch from Yerushalayim to Damascus - so the Mashiach could reach Gan Eden.
